# How to change (not reset) password via CMD in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, passwords

On Windows 10 Pro, non-domain

I use:

```
net user <username> <password>
```

But it removes all stored credentials - I lose access to all my encrypted things,
for example, personal certificates no longer work properly. You have to upload them again in the `account <username>`

It removes stored passwords even from third-party apps like Forticlient (a VPN client).

Is there a way to change your password, like how you are able to change your password in Settings, without losing all stored passwords/certificate information?

Comment: To my knowledge, `net user <username> *` is the only way to do it using command line, but why do you want to use commandline, and not simply press ctrl-alt-del, change password? that is imho the quickest option. Ctrl-alt-end if you are on a remote session.

Comment: If you are trying to change the password as another user then you can only reset the password.  Why can’t you log into the user and change the password?